# ASP.NET Core controller constructor: access request information

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a base controller class with `ILog log` field, which is set at constructor from custom logger service, passed via dependency injection.

I'd like to access something like request context **in controller constructor** to get arbitrary HTTP header or `HttpContext.Items` or something like that to use it when creating my `log`.

I tried using `IHttpContextAccessor`. It gives me `DefaultHttpContext` which does not contain `Items` added by middleware.

The only thing that i can imagine is to make `log` property of controller `public` and write an `IActionFilter` which sets this property. Because action filters have access to both context and controller instance.

Not having request context in controller constructor looks weird to me, because request information can be useful to avoid boilerplate code in actions. Controllers are created per request anyway, so there's no harm to use some request data in constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For request level logging use an `ActionFilter` attrbute and inject an `ILogger` to that. I'm not sure but I think in MVC 5+ the dependency injection is supported in action filter attributes. If not, instead of registering in `GlobalFilters`, you can implement an `IFilterProvider` for attaching and instantiating the attribute to the requests you'd like to.

On the other hand, if you need any kind of business level logging (so for example inside an action body), use the injected `ILogger` in the controller, but then you should not call any logging logic until the process is inside an action. At that point you'll already have a built-up request context.